# There are $(p-1)!+1$ elements satisfying $x^p=e$ in $S_p$, where $p$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $p$ is a prime number, show that in $S_p$ there are $(p-1)!+1$ elements $x$ satisfying $x^p=e$.

How to find the solution?
As usual any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element of order $p$ is $S_p$ must necessarily be a cycle of length $p$. How many such cycles are there? Of course $p!$. But, for each cycle you count cyclic shifts as being the same, so you are left with $p!/p=(p-1)!$ different cycles of length $p$. Of course the trivial element satisfies the condition, hence $(p-1)!+1=\#\{x \in S_p: x^p=e\}$.

Comment: Very nice. +1${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: nice explanation...thank you for the explanation.. @Nicky_Hekster

Comment: There is nice application. With this you can prove part of what is called Wilson's Theorem: for every prime $p$, we have $(p-1)! + 1 \equiv 0$ (mod $p$). You can use James McKay's proof of the theorem of Cauchy (the existence of an element of order $p$ in a group of which the order is divisible by $p$). This proof implies that the number of elements of order $p$ in a group is $\equiv -1$ (mod $p$).